# how to Get consumer Key and consumer Secret from Salesforce

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am using .NET Application by passing user(consumer)name I need to retrieve consumer Key and consumer  Secret from Salesforce how can I achieve this.

Comment: Please post a code sample so we can see your data structures and what each contains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Consumer Key and Consumer Secret are available on the Connected App Details page.

> Setup > App Setup > Create > Apps > Connected Apps: *your app* > API (Enable OAuth Settings)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Connected App first. See [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm&language=en_US) for instructions on how to create a Connected App. Once that is done, you will be provided with consumer key and secret.